# unzip a string ziped with gzip

Tags: gzip, compression

I am using an IDS that allows me to look at the responses sent by our servers to an attacker. The problem is that the response is compressed with GZIP. There is no way to save the text as gzip file. Right now my only solution is to bother customer support to have them decompress the text. I have tried several online tools without success. How can I decompress a string?

Comment: I feel like answsering "use gunzip" is not what you expect.  If you can extract data, gunzip is your option, if data cannot be extracted from your tools, it will be hard to do something. The only thing I can think of : disable compress on your server, so that you see full text.

Comment: You are correct. The only method for extracting the data is copy and paste

Comment: If you cannot extract binary by copy paste, I don't see how you can do that. Your IDS does not allow extract of pcap file ?  The simplest option for you is to disable compression on your server for a time to check stuff then reenable it.

Comment: No, but I do have access to the hex payload as in I can copy and paste it as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, if you have the payload in hex from your tool, and you are able to copy/paste it to a file, then

- you can reverse hex to binary with the `xxd` tool
- you can inflate the data with the `gunzip` tool

It will only be ok if you are able to have the full payload for a query.